# Why do we need Canvas in Java 3D?

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm a bit new to Java 3D and I'm trying to clarify everything for myself. I created an app at start and didn't use Canvas3D. But later I needed to interact with a mouse and found tips and tutorials only using Canvas3D class. So do we really need canvas in 3D apps or there's another way to catch the mouse coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class Canvas3D](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html)

*"The Canvas3D class provides a drawing canvas for 3D rendering. It is used either for on-screen rendering or off-screen rendering. Canvas3D is an extension of the AWT Canvas class that users may further subclass to implement additional functionality."*

*"The Canvas3D object extends the Canvas object to include 3D-related information such as the size of the canvas in pixels, the Canvas3D's location, also in pixels, within a Screen3D object, and whether or not the canvas has stereo enabled."*

*"Because all Canvas3D objects contain a reference to a Screen3D object and because Screen3D objects define the size of a pixel in physical units, Java 3D can convert a Canvas3D size in pixels to a physical world size in meters. It can also determine the Canvas3D's position and orientation in the physical world."*

As far as I am aware of, it is not possible to do any java3d visualisation if not inside a Canvas3D

Comment: What do you mean saying 'visualisation'?

Comment: In theory, but your question seems to be stating otherwise, I am not aware of any way to display the 3D image outside a Canvas3D!

Comment: Well, here are the examples:) 
http://www.java3d.org/starting.html 
http://www.java3d.org/lighting.html

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean - but it is not that the Canvas3D is not there, it is just declared implicitly. In the same way, they do not open a Frame as well - it does not mean they are not using one!

Comment: Getting an explicit reference to it is just so you can modify its properties, such as scale, stereo etc.